# How do I use a Moose Type as a regex match expression?

Tags: regex, perl, moose

I have the following type in my class file:

```
has 'cardNumber' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', required => 1);
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
foreach $_ (@accountsInfo) {
      if ($_ =~ m/^$self->cardNumber()/) {
            $self->pushing(split(/,/, $_));
            $self->invokeAccount();
      }
 }
```

But I can't get it to test properly. If I manually type in the number I am looking for in the regex slashes it works perfectly. Can you please help me to use the cardNumber Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print it to see what you're trying to match.  You'll get output like `SOMECLASS=HASH(0x6bbb48)->foo()`.  A solution:

```
/^@{[$self->cardNumber()]}/
```

Comment: Man I LOVE you guys! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Perl's interpolation rules state that arrays (`"@foo"`) and scalars (`"$bar"`), as well as (a) lookups of values in hashes (`"$baz{bar}"`) or arrays (`"$foo[1]"`), and (b) dereferences of the previous cases (`"@$foo, $$bar, $baz->{bar}, $foo->[1]"`) are interpolated into double quoted strings.

Function calls, and per extension method calls, are not interpolated.

You can interpolate arbitrary code into strings by using a trick of dereferencing an anonymous reference. Usually, you want an arrayref:

```
"foo @{[ expressions; ]} bar"; # interpolating anon hashref
```

but scalar refs work as well (they are 1 character longer).

```
"foo ${\( expressions; )}" # interpolating anon scalar ref
```

However, you should consider caching the value you want to interpolate in a scalar variable:

```
my $cardNumber = $self->cardNumber;
for (@accountsInfo) {
  if (/\A\Q$cardNumber\E/) {
    $self->pushing(split /,/);
    $self->invokeAccount();
  }
}
```

Additional note: I stripped out unneccessary parens and mentions of `$_` from that code snippet. Also, I escaped the characters in `$cardNumber` so that they match *literally*, and aren't treated as a regex.